# Protobuf install on mac fails with 'could not symlink'

Tags: macos, homebrew, protobuf-net

Trying to install protobuf on mac via:

```
brew install protobuf
```

Results in:

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink include/google
/usr/local/include is not writable.
```

Suggestion:

```
You can try again using:
  brew link protobuf
```

Results in:

```
Error: Could not symlink include/google
/usr/local/include is not writable.
```

Tried:

```
brew update
brew uninstall protobuf... brew install protobuf
sudo brew... of course won't work (cowards...)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like this solves it:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

and then:

```
brew link --overwrite protobuf
```

Taken from here:

http://developpeers.com/blogs/fix-for-homebrew-permission-denied-issues